# Writing a DataContext that talks to multiple controllers with breeze

Tags: breeze

Breeze is the best , is Entity Frameworks for javascrpit , and more, but also reduces the calls to  database, is so impressive to see it in action (Ctrl-Shift-J).

In the intermediate plural sight SPA video, then changed that uow to be a breezeAPI Uow, which removed the repository factory and provider, very simple http://grab.by/nkU2. everything works awesome http://grab.by/nkUo. got many more ideas from here http://www.breezejs.com/samples/temphire-sample.

now my question, 
what about if we need many controllers. so in other words how we have many SPAs in our application, so in the John Papa breeze implementation will means having many datacontext.js.

We may latter need to build a dashboard for employees for example , and then maybe another SPA Dashboard for Products, and so on, so the one controller / one datacontext.js apporach will not be wise

Here is the InvoicingSPA which uses John Papa datacontext.js based on the Open Source Code Camper
http://sdrv.ms/14snOPx

And here is the TempHire v2 in which I added the UnitOfWork (C#) and a Entity Framework Repository to get a nice UOW on the controller
http://sdrv.ms/14snWhY

Comment: Oscar - I've written some controllers in DocCode that will support most of the scenarios you describe. I've only got a limited time budget. I cannot promise to cover all scenarios with every possible solution. I cannot promise to do anything with your specific cases although I very much appreciate your effort in producing them. I expect to have something to talk about tomorrow or Wednesday

Comment: Yes, and thank you, unfortunately is missing durandal, and also that great DocCode app touches so many amazing parts that is probably way too much for someone trying to learn breeze to prepare a vertical slide. 
We have all felt in love with your awesome TempHire app but I think is overly complicated .. In 2 months from now, we will say, wow this is so easy and logical. 
But for simple mortals like me, it will be nice to have something like the John Papa DataContext.js not just for one controller, Something simple but that keeps the amazing pattern of simplicity and Durandal all over.

Comment: i did my best on the 2 apps above (on skydrive) , maybe in your experts hands will be a super quick win

Comment: something very interesting, in only 3 days this question has been seen 155 times, which (probably) means that many developers are also interested . but that is hard to say..
i just want to say. Thank you for creating breeze, because of you the web data acquisition will never be the same.

Comment: I totally agree. I have the controller side done now. I just have to finish the example. Can't get to it this week. Week of 24th I can polish it off. Sorry for the wait.

Answer (score 0):

after working heavily with breeze intellisense i think i found the answer about the  easiest way to have 2 or 3 SPAs on the same application 
http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_setProperties
is done very simple in that way

Regards

Comment: This comment did absolutely nothing to resolve the question of how to use multiple api controllers with BreezeJS :(